# About localization of a finitely generated $k$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I've some questions about localization.

My problem is the following.
Let $A$ be a finitely generated domain over a field $k$. We know by hypothesis that its fraction field $K(A)$ is a finite separable extension of a purely trascendental extension $k(T_1, \dots , T_d)$ of $k$ (follows from Noether's Normalization Lemma, right?). Then we can write $K(A)=k(T_1, \dots , T_d)[X]/(P(X))$ where $P$ is irreducible and separable polynomial and without loss of generality we can choose $P(X)$ in $k[T_1, \dots , T_d][X]$ by Gauss' lemma.

Now my book says:

1. There exists a localization $A_f$ of $A$ such that $k[T_1, \dots , T_d][X]/(P(X)) \subseteq  A_f$.
2. As $A$ is a $k$-finitely generated algebra, there exists $R \in k[T_1, \dots , T_d]$ such that $A \subseteq k[T_1, \dots , T_d]_{R}[X]/(P(X))$.

I don't know how to prove the two assertions above. 
Does anyone have some ideas?

Thanks a lot!

PS: If someone is interested in algebraic geometry, this is used by Liu's book to prove that a geometrically reduced variety has a closed regular point.

Comment: "...$K(A)$ is a finite separable extension of a purely inseparable extension $k(T_1, \dots , T_d)$ of $k$" You seem to be confusing purely inseparable with purely transcendental.

Comment: Oh yes!, Sorry I've mistyped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the fact that the rings you're are working with are **finitely generated**. In the first example, note that by the definition of $P$, $k[T_1,\ldots,T_d][X]/(P(X))$ is just a finitely generated subring of $K(A)$.
The second case is almost the same. Consider the generators of $k$-algebra $A$, pick $R$ for each one of them and finally take a product of all $R$'s.